# Random link generator script output issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random, hyperlink

Am have trouble with random link script and will need some help

I want it setup so that anytime i reload the page it displays a random anchor text with link in it.
eg. if reload page **Go to site**  <-- This should change displaying a new link in anchor text each time depending on num of links set

```
//specify total # of random links
var totallinks=4
```

i need an array that stores links and displays them every time page is loaded with anchor text.Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You forgot to include a question in your question. "I want" and "I need" do not a question make...

Comment: Also, try to include code you've already tried. We're here to help, not do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

well, you could do this:

```
// write your array like this in json format
var linksArray = [
     { 
      text:"ABC",
      link:"abc.html"
     },
     { 
      text:"DEF",
      link:"def.html"
     },
     { 
      text:"GHI",
      link:"ghi.html"
     }
   ];

// get random index each time
var randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * linksArray.length)),
    text = linksArray[randomIndex].text,
    link = linksArray[randomIndex].link;

// set href link and text of link
$("#link").attr("href",link).text(text);
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8yDTh/1/

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the help sir will try that and let you know how it goes